# Installing updates/patches for bug fixes in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, installation

I'm trying to fix [this bug](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/731) in QGIS 2.0.

I suppose the code, under the "Files Changed' tab needs to be copied/installed somewhere?   Could you please advise on how to do so? I cannot find any help page on this - but may have been Google-ing the wrong terms.

More broadly (but not my immediate concern) - why are these changes just not corrected in the original source code?

Answer (score 2):

Generally you can't just install a patch like that.  That is a source code patch and needs to be merged into the source code and then a binary is built.

This change has been merged into code already and should be in 2.0.

**Note:**  I have noticed this is a Python patch.  In that case you are in luck.

Save both these files https://raw.github.com/ddanielvaz/Quantum-GIS/8a50ddb93f4cad0cdf7ff631eef44c60e19ffc68/python/plugins/fTools/tools/doGeoprocessing.py and https://raw.github.com/ddanielvaz/Quantum-GIS/8a50ddb93f4cad0cdf7ff631eef44c60e19ffc68/python/plugins/fTools/tools/ftools_utils.py

Save them over the top of the ones in `{yourqgis install}/python/plugins/fTools/tools/`

Comment: Partial fix? The ftools_utils file assigns polygon name correctly... but seems to delete some polygons? I dont have a doGeoprocessing.py file? I'm on a Mac... Still working on it.. Also, this error remains in 2.0.